# usernames in nfs share between nfs server (CentOS) and nfs client (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, nfs, share

I have a NFS server (CentOs 6.9) and a NFS client (Ubuntu 16.04). I have installed nfs-utils and rpcbind on the server. The server configurations are as follow:
/etc/exports

```
/home 192.168.1.11(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sync)
```

/etc/idmapd.conf

```
[General]
Domain = local.domain.edu
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody
[Translation]
Method = nsswitch
```

On ubuntu I have installed nfs-common and of course it automatically installed rpcbind too. I configured the nfs related files as follow:
/etc/idmapd.conf

```
[General]
Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = local.domain.edu
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
[Translation]
Method = nsswitch
```

/etc/default/nfs-common

```
STATDOPTS=
NEED_GSSD= no
NEED_IDMAPD =yes
```

and I use the following command to mount the shared folder on the client:

```
mount 192.168.1.110:/home /home
```

until now everything is OK. But the problem is that when I mount the shared folder, permissions are strange! and all of them are as follow:

```
drwx--x--x  3 nobody 4294967294      4096 Aug 14 01:27 wiki
```

I have added all the users in server side to the client side with its related UID and GID.
If I reboot the client server everything gets OK:

```
drwx--x--x 20 wiki       wiki            4096 Aug 15 05:19 wiki
```

Another problem is that when I add a new folder with new ownership and permissions, it does not get update on the client even if I restart the rpcbind and nfs-utils servives:

```
systemctl restart rpcbind
systemctl restart nfs-utils.service
```

and I have to reboot to the new changes take effect!! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sinai. Did you find the solution to your problem?